# What causes the 'Unknown format "factory"' error in this Laravel 8 app?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am working on a Laravel 8 app with users and posts.

The objective is to create a bunch of posts (I already have users).

```
namespace Database\Factories;
// import Post model
use App\Models\Post;
// import User model
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class PostFactory extends Factory {
  /**
   * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
   *
   * @var string
   */
   protected $model = Post::class;
 
  /**
   * Define the model's default state.
   *
   * @return array
   */
   public function definition() {
    return [
            'title' => $this->faker->sentence(3),
            'description' => $this->faker->text,
            'content' => $this->faker->paragraph,
            'user_id' => $this->faker->factory(App\Models\User::class),
        ];
    }
}
```

#### The problem

I run `php artisan tinker` then `Post::factory()->count(100)->create()` in the terminal and I get:

```
InvalidArgumentException with message 'Unknown format "factory"'
```

#### UPDATE

I replace my return statement with:

```
 return [
    'title' => $this->faker->sentence(3),
    'description' => $this->faker->text,
    'content' => $this->faker->paragraph,
    'user_id' => User::factory(),
];
```

I get this in the terminal:

```
Class 'Database\Factories\UserFactory' not found
```

##### Questions:

1. Where is my mistake?
2. Does the fact that I get the error `Class 'Database\Factories\UserFactory' not found` mean that I need to
   create a `UserFactory` factory? Because there isn't one. (I wanted
   to create *posts*, not users).

Comment: try by adding a "\" before App to App\Models\User::class

Comment: @Mike I get `Aliasing 'Post' to 'App\Models\Post' for this Tinker session.` and `InvalidArgumentException with message 'Unknown format "factory"'` in the terminal.

Comment: in the factory, try to do that change at user_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a `UserFactory` factory and using the below return statement did the trick:

```
return [
    'title' => $this->faker->sentence(3),
    'description' => $this->faker->text,
    'content' => $this->faker->paragraph,
    'user_id' => User::factory(),
];
```

So, the `PostFactory` class looks like this:

```
class PostFactory extends Factory {
  /**
   * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
   *
   * @var string
   */
   protected $model = Post::class;
 
  /**
   * Define the model's default state.
   *
   * @return array
   */
   public function definition() {
        return [
                'title' => $this->faker->sentence(3),
                'description' => $this->faker->text,
                'content' => $this->faker->paragraph,
                'user_id' => User::factory(),
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't suppose there is `$this->faker->factory(..)`.

You can do

`'user_id' => App\Models\User::factory()->create()->id,`

EDIT:
`'user_id' => App\Models\User::factory(),`

Comment: I get `Class 'Database\Factories\UserFactory' not found` from the terminal.

Comment: Add `use HasFactory;` to your user model.

Comment: Where, in what file?

Comment: App\Models\User

Comment: It is already there, I am using it.

Comment: Does the fact that I get the error `Class 'Database\Factories\UserFactory' not found` mean that I need to create a `UserFactory` factory? Because there isn't one. (I wanted to create *posts*, not users).

Comment: I suppose so, if you want posts linked to users